# How to Check Paypal Recurring Users payment status in Cron job?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm Working on a subscription based payment option in using Paypal in php

Below is the form i use for subscription payment

```
<form name = "myform" action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "post" target = "_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type = "hidden" name = "business" value = "test-facilitator@sample.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type = "hidden" name = "item_name" value = "Patient Trasportation">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">        
<!--<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="1">-->
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input id="subValue" type="hidden" name="t3" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type = "hidden" name = "cancel_return" value = "http://www.example/Process">
<input type = "hidden" name = "return" value = "http://www.example/buy">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo  $last_ins_id; ?>">        
<input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary btn-paypal' value="Pay with Paypal">
</form>
```

Using this i will store the needed Payment details after success return of the paypal , The return values are below,

```
Array
(
    [txn_type] => subscr_signup
    [subscr_id] => I-WJ5JU5F5J4EL
    [last_name] => singh
    [residence_country] => US
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_name] => Test
    [business] => test.zerosoft-facilitator@sample.com
    [amount3] => 40.00
    [recurring] => 1
    [address_street] => 1 Main St
    [payer_status] => verified
    [payer_email] => test@test.com
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [first_name] => test
    [receiver_email] => test.zerosoft-facilitator@sample.com
    [address_country_code] => US
    [payer_id] => RTNTA7JN44S7S
    [address_city] => San Jose
    [reattempt] => 1
    [payer_business_name] => mano singh's Test Store
    [address_state] => CA
    [subscr_date] => 03:54:15 Jul 28, 2016 PDT
    [address_zip] => 95131
    [custom] => 206
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [period3] => 1 W
    [address_country] => United States
    [mc_amount3] => 40.00
    [address_name] => Test Store
    [auth] => AimgDlXpiQ7gYXJgDylV-75JQwlPSBkduKhg79fKg2.8qxXDZ4w51lgCVLg.20WJk1jT0USO27QbLUZBnGZKm8A
    [form_charset] => UTF-8
)
```

Now i need to check all users payment status once in a month using Cron job and Check their payment status and increase the validity date for them or block them. I Googled out an didn't got solution any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

When using Standard Subscriptions there are no APIs available to hit and pull profile details, but you will get additional IPNs each time a payment is processed, so you can just update based on that instead of using a cron job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , Is there Any API which can be used to get subscription details for 2nd time and the next level f\of auto payment in php ? if you have any reference please share here

Comment: If you want API access to profiles you'll need to use the Recurring Payments APIs instead of Standard Subscriptions.  IPN will trigger for every payment, though, whether it's the 1st, second, or 1000th.